# How to use setState inside render function without onClick event

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render

i have map function inside render and i want to setState if some condition satisfied inside the map function, how to setState inside render function.
i have following code

```
render(){
      progressNum = this.state.progressData.map((data,index) => {
      {
      data.status=="unmarked"?
      this.setState({
      checkd:true,
      })
      :
      this.setState({
      checkd:false,
      })

}

....}
```

problem:loop call to render

Comment: you are already doing `setState`. are you facing any issue?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're actually trying to do. You shouldn't directly call `setState()` in `render()`, that's for sure.

Comment: state should not be set in render function independently it should be triggerd

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should not be setting state in the render function as that will trigger another render and you might end up in an infinite loop of rendering.

Comment: i know but how i can set state or pass data to another function

Comment: You could pass data without setting state... and you could do operations based on your current state without setting it

Answer (score 1):

**Render function should not contain any side effect.**

one can define business processing in another function and called it from inside of render.

```
mineFuntion=()=> {

  const progressData = {...this.state.progressData};

  progressData.map((data, index) => {

      if(data.status == "unmarked"){
        data.checkd =  true;
      }else{
        data.checkd =  false;
      }
      return data;
  });

  return progressData;
}
```

**Inside render :**

```
render(){
   const progressData = this.mineFuntion();//do UI stuf with progressData 
}
```